# Jquery Datatables render multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using the datatables plugin for jQuery however I am having issues with the render function:

I have a string that contains some html elements in a column, I do not want the html elements to render in the table so I use the function `$.fn.dataTable.render.text()`

I also only want this data to be a preview as the string can be incredibly long therefore I am using an ellipsis function `$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(40)`

The ellipsis function is defined [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Text-helper):

```
// https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Text-helper
$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis = function (cutoff) {
    return function (data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
            var str = data.toString(); // cast numbers

            return str.length < cutoff ?
                str :
                str.substr(0, cutoff - 1) + '&#8230;';
        }

        // Search, order and type can use the original data
        return data;
    };
};
```

Would it be possible to combine these functions in any way?

The closest solution to my problem is [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43160/multi-render-renderer) found on the datatables forum.
This is exactly what I want to do however it does not work as `d = renderArray[r](d, type, row, meta);` is not a function.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
[image: Table of available renders]

---

[image: Error of function not defined]

Comment: Check out `console.table( $.fn.dataTable.render )` it will output a table of the renderers you have available, I'll bet you miss one of the renderers you are trying to use. Include what you are missing and I am sure it will work.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks! Both renders work separately successfully, however the problem I am having is that I cannot apply both to a single column.

Comment: You just use `$.fn.dataTable.render.multi` as you mentioned, I tried it out 01.12 in a fiddle (can easily make a new one) and it is a brilliant solution. But it only works if you have all the renderers present.

Comment: @davidkonrad Would it be possible to show me that fiddle as I cant seem to resolve it myself, I have also updated the question with a screenshot of the table. would the fact that the name is missing from the tables effect how they work?

Comment: I did not save the link, here is a new one **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1006/** using ellipsis and moment, DT version 1.10.1

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for your help, my version however is not working still, there must be some sort of other issue, ill keep looking into it :(

Answer (score 0):

The mRender function is passed the data for the whole row. So, you can access any property you want to access render multiple function using datatables

```
{
    mData: "bar",
    mRender: function(data, type, val) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'display':
                return '<a href="/data/' + data.foo + '">' + data.bar + '</a>';
                break;
            // optionally, add case statements for 'sort', 'filter', and 'type'
            default:
                return data.bar;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```